# The dangers of using AJAX as a front end for the website

Tags: java, ajax, security, frontend

We have Java EE backend for database access. Servlets ask for XML data and send XML response according to them. Now we have to write frontend for it. The idea is to communicate with backend through jQuery AJAX sending xml requests to Java backend and process data on client side.

**Question is:** Are there any security holes, and is it worth of writing frontend using Java/JSP?

Comment: AJAX should be used to display data, and to submit user-created data. It is worth using for the user interface, but not any kind of calculation. In other words, have the server check EVERYTHING the client sends, and never trust the client.

Comment: Please show me a web technology that has absolutely no security holes whatsoever. Does one exist? Could one possibly ever exist?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how about google's search?

Comment: @ChristianStewart: based on [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) I can tell you that there is no way to state categorically that Google's search or that any web technology is free from security holes.

Comment: I'd recommend writing your frontend using Java/JSP considering that JavaScript can be disabled. In terms of security, well, it depends on how you sanitize the AJAX requests I guess. (I don't know any better than you and my guess is as good as yours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security hole can happen regardless of the technology you use. Both XML & Jquery & Ajax and Java & JSP can have security holes. You have to consider what information resides where, how would hacker hack your application etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's far too general a question to answer, but when writing a client-side application you would typically need to put some consideration into:

- ensuring that security controls such as input validation and authorisation checking are still performed correctly on the server side and not left to client-controlled JavaScript to sort out. You should not assume that an attacker cannot call an AJAX action just because the feature that does so is not visible in the UI; have a tester try to manually send AJAX requests for logged-in actions or actions on resources belonging to one user, when logged out or logged in as a different user.
- ensuring that the client-side script doesn't have any HTML-injection holes resulting in XSS vulnerabilities. For example in jQuery use of `html()` (or the related `append()`, `before()` etc manipulation methods) with a string of markup that contains variables - use the `$('<element>', {dynamic attributes})` creation shortcut instead. Similarly in plain JS prefer `createElement`/`setAttribute` to `innerHTML`.
- ensuring that the client-side script doesn't have any JS-injection holes resulting in XSS vulnerabilities. Avoid setting strings for timeouts or inline event handlers; use function objects and proper event handling (eg jQuery `.on()`) instead.

When considering writing an application as client-side JS+AJAX instead of middle-tier HTML+forms, the question you have to ask is whether you can survive your app being unusable in user agents that don't support the JavaScript you require:

- legacy browsers
- new browsers hitting bugs you don't know about yet
- crucially - search engines

if you're happy with that, and doing the additional work to make JS usable/accessible, then it can make sense.

Comment: Thank you alot for your answer.  I see, that jQuery/AJAX is suitable for our situation. We check all requests on the server side, and we don't need indexing information by search engine because all our data are about clients and their transactions.